# \\.\COM13: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, c, windows, serial-port

I have written a C program in order to open COM port in windows(in my case it is COM13) using "createFile" function which is in <windows.h> header in the following way:

```c
HANDLE comm;

const char* port = "\\\\.\\COM13";

comm = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

I'm getting the above mentioned error even though I had connected the COM port. Also I tried to open the same COM port using the python script using serial module, I was able to open it successfully. I wonder what would be the problem. Why it is failing to detect the COM port when I use this? Any suggestion in the correction of the above code?

Comment: Is it because FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL(0x80) is specified? [CreateFileA function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) Please try setting it to 0. [HOWTO: Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/115831/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9)

Comment: I used CreateFileA function, it opened successfully. Thank you